# Python Shifting a Value to Columns Based on a Condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing a problem related to a delivery offset in the example dataset.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Platform ID' : [1,2,3,4], "2018" : [0,0,0,0],
                                              "2019" : [0,0,0,0], 
                                              "2020" : [21,3,8,23], 
                                              "2021" : [31,0,10,12], 
                                              "2022" : [2,23,13,14],
                   'Offsets (in months)' : [6, 12, 18, 0]})
df
```

What I need is a time shift based on the last column if the delivery is 6 months the half of the value should go to the previous year's column.  If the time shift is 12 months the whole value must move to the previous year's column. If the time shift is 18 the value must move to the previous column and one-half of it must move even further like by 6 months in the first case.

I tried to use shift() however it moves the whole column. Is there a way how to set this condition in this or another function?

Desired output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Platform ID' : [1,2,3,4], "2018" : [0,0,4,0],
                                              "2019" : [10.5,3,9,0], 
                                              "2020" : [26,0,11.5,23], 
                                              "2021" : [16.5,23,6.5,12], 
                                              "2022" : [1,0,0,14],
                   'Offsets (in months)' : [6, 12, 18, 0]})
df
```

[image]

Comment: If the question is unclear please let me know and I will try my best to explain. Thank you very much for your help! I spent already some hours getting the solution, however it is difficult for me where to start.

Comment: Isn't row #1 incorrect? If the whole value is supposed to shift 1 year, why is 2019 valued at 8 and 2022 split by half as though it's equivalent to the 6 month offset shift?

Comment: Yes, you are right the row is wrong, it should be moved only to the next columns. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Now it is correct :) thank you again!

Comment: I assume your dataset is much larger than the example? Would it be problematic to do each of the four rows separately?

Comment: Also, I believe the 2019 in row #2 is wrong. You've left it as 4, but it should also receive 5 from the original 10 in the year 2021 and thus sum up to 9.

Comment: You got me :D yes, you are right I cannot do basic math. Corrected! The whole dataset is much larger. It goes from 2010-2040 (however it is always 6, 12, 18 or 0 months)

Comment: Oh. Then ignore my answer. I will post an amended one later on. If you want to give it a go, you could for instance filter based on the offset and run a similar solution as the one I posted, but modified to run over every row.

Comment: It would be nice when you can continue, as I said I have been working on it for some time already and am very curious about the best possible solution :) Again THANK YOU for your time :)

Comment: I had time to check my answer and it worked. Let me know if it's unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in no way the most elegant solution out there, but given that each row essentially follows a different functional shift, I can't think of a much neater way of doing it than the below. I have amended my previous answer to adjust it to the new provided information. If a neater answer exists, I would be curious to see it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Platform ID' : [1,2,3,4], "2018" : [0,0,0,0],
                                              "2019" : [0,0,0,0], 
                                              "2020" : [21,3,8,23], 
                                              "2021" : [31,0,10,12], 
                                              "2022" : [2,23,13,14],
                   'Offsets (in months)' : [6, 12, 18, 0]})
for i in df['Offsets (in months)'].unique():
    if i == 6:
        df_6 = df[df['Offsets (in months)'] == 6]
        df_6.iloc[:,1:6] = (df_6.iloc[:,1:6]/2).shift(periods=-1, fill_value=0, axis=1) +df_6.iloc[:,1:6]/2
        df[df['Offsets (in months)'] == 6] = df_6
    elif i == 12:
        df_12 = df[df['Offsets (in months)'] == 12]
        df_12.iloc[:,1:6] = df_12.iloc[:,1:6].shift(periods=-1, fill_value=0, axis=1)
        df[df['Offsets (in months)'] == 12] = df_12
    elif i == 18:
        df_18 = df[df['Offsets (in months)'] == 18]
        df_18.iloc[:,1:6] = df_18.iloc[:,1:6].shift(periods=-1, fill_value=0, axis=1)
        df_18.iloc[:,1:6] = (df_18.iloc[:,1:6]/2).shift(periods=-1, fill_value=0, axis=1) +df_18.iloc[:,1:6]/2
        df[df['Offsets (in months)'] == 18] = df_18
```

Unless there is a typo, this should do the trick. I am rushed so I might have made a mistake. Basically, the idea is to filter out each of the offsets using boolean indexing and then shifting the values excluding Platform ID and Offset (by specifying iloc[1:6].

Comment: Check out my new answer.

Comment: THANK YOU very much, this works and it is a very convenient solution also for a bigger dataset :) Let me know if I can somehow confirm your skill or give some credit to you as I really appreciate your attitude :)))

Comment: No problem! Nothing is necessary. If something about why it works is unclear, don't hesitate to ask.